# How to create a stop-filter (instead of a pass-filter) when reading CAN messages? [C++, Linux]

Tags: c++, c, linux, can-bus, socketcan

I am using a SocketCAN to access the CAN bus. 
I have successfully created pass-filters like this:

```
struct can_filter m_Filter;
// ... setting up m_Filters
setsockopt(m_CanSockId, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_FILTER, m_Filter,
           sizeof(struct can_filter));
```

This instructs to let CAN messages pass when meeting the filter settings.

Now I want to create a stop-filter but I do not know how to do it.
For example: I wish to let all CAN messages pass except the ones with ID 0x18DAF101.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have looked in this documentation [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) without finding anything to try, that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the bit `CAN_INV_FILTER` in your filter to invert the filter logic.

From the documentation behind the link you have provided:

> The filter can be inverted in this semantic, when the CAN_INV_FILTER
>     bit is set in can_id element of the can_filter structure.

Comment: thank you! I will check asap but I already trust this is what I need!